# What is the correct way of designing the promote() mechanism in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction

I try to build a Customer manager program in c++. In my program, there is Customer class (base class), Guest (derived from customer), VIP (derived from Guest), a vector<Customer*> array in the main to store all customers. So if I want to promote a Guest object from the vector, what is the best way of doing that. I did think about the downcast approach but are there any other ways to promote Guest to VIP.

```
Class Customer {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(string name);
};

Class Guest : public Customer {
public:
    Guest();
    Guest(string name);
}

Class VIP : public Guest {
private:
    int VIPPoints;
public:
    VIP();
    VIP(string name);
}
```

Comment: Create a `VIP` ctor that takes `Guest&&`

Comment: Lacking a solid explanation of how their behavior differs, it looks like one class containing `bool guest; std::optional<int> VIPpoints;` would do the job.

Comment: There are a very large number of ways to do this. For example, I would personally probably only have a `Customer` class, with a `std::vector<Customer> guests` and `std::vector<Customer> vips` and some data structure to track the points. If OOP was necessary, I'd probably split out the customer's "status" into a separate type, so that a `Customer` has a `Status` where its status could be `VIP` or `GUEST`, or possibly even make the `Status` have the inheritance hierarchy with `Customer` having no inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can create CustomerWrpapper class which will wrap union on Guest & VIP and enum to identify customer type.

```
class CustomerWrapper {
public:
    enum CustomerType
    {
        guest,
        vip
    };  
    
    CustomerWrapper(const Guest& guest);
    CustomerWrapper(const VIP& vip);
    CustomerWrapper& operator=(const Guest& guest);
    CustomerWrapper& operator=(const VIP& vip);

private:
    CustomerType type;
    union {
        Guest guest;
        VIP vip;
    };
};
```

and then you can create vector of this wrapper

```
vector<CustomerWrapper*> customers;
```